# phpmyadmin and import of an existing database

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I have just installed `phpmyadmin` on a Windows 2008 Sever with IIS installed and I want to important a database which I have created on my own machine onto this server within `phpmyadmin`.

When I try do so I get an error message

> File could not be read

I have read this may be due to the `open_basedir` within `php.ini`

I have changed open_basedir to `open_basedir = D:\inetpub` and then placed the `database.sql.zip` file into the inetpub folder but I am still getting the same error message.

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this article. http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/forums/forum/72909/topic/3817584

I don't know why that works but seemed to help that case.  My answer to you is don't use phpmyadmin as a crutch.  You should at least learn the basic mysql syntax to import your database from the command line.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Comment: +1 for "don't use phpmyadmin as a crutch"